# How we can avoide from error Timestamp format must be YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS[.FFFFFFFFF] when date-time input has no any date-time value?

Tags: java, ofbiz

I'm new in Java, i use Java with OFBiz, i have a search form that has date-time input field for searching, when no date-time is selected and form submitted, in Java follow error occur:

```
Timestamp format must be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[.FFFFFFFFF]
```

So how i can avoid from this? bellow is my code block:

```
String sDate = request.getParameter('sdate_field');
if(sDate != null)
{
     condition = new EntityXpr("crt_date",Operator.LESS_THAN_EQUAL_TO,Timestamp.valueOf(sDate));
}
```

Comment: Change `if(sDate != null)` to `if(!"".equals(sDate)` :)

Answer (score 1):

In OFBiz you can do

```java
if (UtilValidate.isNotEmpty(userLogin)) {
    condition = new EntityXpr("crt_date",Operator.LESS_THAN_EQUAL_TO,Timestamp.valueOf(sDate));
}
```

See `org.ofbiz.base.util.*` for more convenience methods.